# "Choose File" in "seleniumlibrary" in robotframework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm trying to browse multiple files (one after the other ) using the keyword "Choose File" for the attached screen.

- The circled in red are the web elements through which files are to be browsed ( top right ).
- The page code is highlighted in red.
- The xpath circled in black ( bottom left )  , which when searched, highlights both the web elements one after another which browse the file.

[image: The screen shot of the web elements]

Below are my steps:

```
Scroll Element Into View    xpath=//span[contains(@class,'filebrowse .click')]  
Wait Until Element is visible   xpath=//span[contains(@class,'filebrowse .click')]  
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//span[contains(@class,'filebrowse .click')]  
Choose File xpath=//span[contains(@class,'filebrowse .click')]  ${file_path}
```

I got the error below for the step above - "Choose File" :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 
(ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

Comment: add html code snip of red circled elements

Comment: Here is the code snippet :

    <span role="button" class="btn btn-primary filebrowse .click dz-clickable"></span>

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and worked fine.

Libraries Used :

```
Library           pyautogui
Library           ImageHorizonLibrary
```

Code sample :

```
Scroll Element Into View    xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Wait Until Element is visible   xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Click Element   xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Sleep   5s
pyautogui.Typewrite file_name.jpg
pyautogui.Key Down  'enter'
ImageHorizonLibrary.Press Combination   Key.enter
Sleep   15s
```

For this I had to keep the file "file_name.jpg" in a default browse folder.
Identified the default folder through a sample code run.