# How to upload a file using "Choose File" keyword in robot framework

Tags: java, swing, robotframework, jfilechooser

How to upload a file using the "Choose File" keyword in the robot framework. 
For testing purposes, I have used this URL i.e.i.e. https://imagetopdf.com/ and below is the code.

URL is easily accessible - Appreciate if any can try and provide the solution.

```
*** Variables ***
${UploadFiletest}           xpath=//div[@id="pick-files"]
${AddFile}          C:\download.jpg 

*** Test Cases ***
Test for Upload
    Open the Browser and Login to eCare WebPage    ${BROWSER}    ${URL_test}
    Upload file

*** Keywords ***
Upload file
    Wait Until Page Contains Element   ${UploadFiletest}   60s
    click element ${UploadFiletest}
    Choose File UploadFiletest AddFile
```

Comment: So, what is your issue?

Comment: Issue: It opens up the file explorer but it does not navigate to the path and select the file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to click on the control to upload a file - selenium (and thus - Robot Framework's SeleniumLibrary) does it by setting the file path as a value of the input element, in the html.
So when you do click on it, the OS file selection dialog opened - but selenium has no control over it.

Another thing - I don't know is this the actual source you're using, but the `Choose File` call had an error - you are not passing variables to it, but strings. It should be like this:

```
Choose File    ${UploadFiletest}    ${AddFile}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Todor. I have commented out the click element ${UploadFiletest} and ya for some reason i was not able to put up a question in the variable format i.e. Choose File    ${UploadFiletest}    ${AddFile}                                                 While i have commented the click control and tried again but still its not able to go to the path and pick the file.

Comment: look like his website using another customize choose file type. It's not default

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the `Choose file` Keyword we need not click on the button and choose the file as we do manually. The keyword internally searches for the file in your specified location and inputs the same to the locator on the webpage and moreover, we need to select the locator with attribute input and having type ="file" as I have mentioned in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em9AW.png). While specifying the file path we need to use forward slash `/` in Robot Framework as mentioned under [path separators in OS Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html).

```
*** Variables ***
${UploadFiletest}           css=[type='file']
${AddFile}          C:/download.jpg

*** Test Cases ***
Test for Upload
    Open Browser      https://imagetopdf.com/    Chrome
    Upload file

*** Keywords ***
Upload file
    Wait Until Page Contains Element   ${UploadFiletest}   60s
    Scroll Element Into View     ${UploadFiletest}
    Choose File     ${UploadFiletest}     ${AddFile}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with the other libraries :

```
Library           pyautogui
Library           ImageHorizonLibrary
```

code sample :

```
Scroll Element Into View    xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Wait Until Element is visible   xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Click Element   xpath=//div[1]/div[5]/a/span
Sleep   5s
pyautogui.Typewrite file_name.jpg
pyautogui.Key Down  'enter'
ImageHorizonLibrary.Press Combination   Key.enter
Sleep   15s
```

For this I had to keep the file "file_name.jpg" in a default browse folder. Identified the default folder through a sample code run.

more details - ["Choose File" in "seleniumlibrary" in robotframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426086/choose-file-in-seleniumlibrary-in-robotframework?noredirect=1#comment95664473_54426086)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your test example, in this URL https://imagetopdf.com, the upload takes place in 2 phases: first it is loaded via a loading bar and then it is uploaed.
Choose File of selenium works only to upload files in a simple way (with a click of a button).
for this it uses the AutoItLibrary library with the Send command.